# c# load images from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to load images from a folder and then inserting them into a  tag.

For now i have this that i took from another question:

```
public string GetImage()
    {

        string imPath;
        imPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Layout/Images/Banner");

        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(imPath);
        FileInfo[] fileInfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

        foreach (FileInfo fi in fileInfo)
                arrayList.Add(fi.FullName);



        return imPath;
    }
```

But its not returning the images, only the folder path.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you have? Do you _understand_ this code?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Do not use non-generic collections.

Comment: This is very puzzling. I am not even sure what you're trying to accomplish. You're mapping a path, then looping thru the files in that folder only to throw it all away and just return the path???

Comment: what i wanted to do is reutrn the images path bu, returning the fodler path is my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Just adding an answer so I can point out what everyone is confused about here.

What you've done here:

```
public string GetImage()
{

    string imPath;
    imPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Layout/Images/Banner");

    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(imPath);
    FileInfo[] fileInfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    foreach (FileInfo fi in fileInfo)
            arrayList.Add(fi.FullName);


    return imPath;
}
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
public string GetImage()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Layout/Images/Banner");
}
```

This is why everyone is a little confused.

Perhaps this is what you want (refactored a little bit)?

```
public ArrayList GetImage()
{
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Layout/Images/Banner"));
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    foreach (FileInfo fi in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            arrayList.Add(fi.FullName);

    return arrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you return the image path.. You probably want the ArrayList you're making.

change:

```
return imPath;
```

to:

```
return arrayList;
```

and change:

```
public string GetImage()
```

to:

```
public ArrayList GetImage()
```

I also reccomend renaming that arraylist, and try to do a little more research before asking questions. If you understood what return is, you would've know what the problem is.

And as you can read in the comments of your question, you shouldn't be using ArrayList. I'm no expert on C# so that will have to be answered by someone else.